# What is the best way of including a JS file from JS code?

Tags: javascript

What is the recommended way of including a Javascript file from another Javascript file?

Answer (score 5):

Most people add the JavaScript file to the head of the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var newfile=document.createElement('script');
  newfile.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  newfile.setAttribute("src", '/myscript.js');
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newfile);
</script>
```

Comment: @Ryan: Argh! I was just posting that! ;)

Answer (score 3):

There are libraries that'll do this for you. You can also add a script tag to your document pointing to the file you want to load (from js), which is simplest, but has problems.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuiloader/

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Edit: I see a lot of answers that add a script tag to the head of your document. As I said this simple solution has a problem, namely you won't know when the browser has finished loading the script you requested, so you wont know when you can call this code. If you want to use a solution like this you should also add a callback somehow to tell you when the required code was loaded.

Comment: adding a callback is a perfectly reasonable thing to do - at the end of the day every library's bootstrapping is just an implementation of this technique, Ryan Doherty just posted a simple example.

Comment: Lazy Load plugin is about lazy loading images. It does not load JavaScript files.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has [getScript()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript) function. Also note that Lazy Load mentioned above is only for images. Not for JavaScript files.

```
$.getScript(url, [callback]);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

([original link](http://www.cryer.co.uk/resources/javascript/script17_include_js_from_js.htm))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Function to allow one JavaScript file to be included by another.
// Copyright (C) 2006-08 www.cryer.co.uk
function IncludeJavaScript(jsFile)
{
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'
    + jsFile + '"></scr' + 'ipt>'); 
}
</script>
```

and then to include a second JavaScript file simply add the line:

```
IncludeJavaScript('secondJS.js');
```

The page that came from includes some gotchas that arise from this approach, so it's worth looking at before using the method.

Comment: If you use that after the document has loaded your are in for a surprise since document.write will replace your active document.

Comment: Also, there is no need to split the the closing tag in two parts. Since everything in the script tag according to (x)HTML DTD is PCDATA (parsed character data) you have to escape the end-tag </ like this: "<\/script>"

Comment: should be DOM assembled which makes the second point moot though

Answer (score 0):

Theres also an function built into [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) that is very easy to use.

```
Scriptaculous.require("path/to/script.js");
```

Worth knowing, since Scriptaculous is a very common javascript library these days.

Answer (score 0):

[Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) does it using `dojo.require()`:

```
dojo.require("your.module.name");
```

Normally this is a synchronous operation done with [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHR). But if you use the xDomain build it will be asynchronous and `dojo.addOnLoad()` will be raised when the script is loaded.

Read more about it:

- [Modules](http://dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-3-programmatic-dijit-and-dojo/modules-and-namespaces)
- [What dojo.require does](http://dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-3-programmatic-dijit-and-dojo/modules-and-namespaces/what-does-dojo-require-)
- [Quickstart: custom builds](http://docs.dojocampus.org/quickstart/custom-builds) (includes xDomain explanation)
- [Cross-domain Dojo](http://docs.dojocampus.org/quickstart/cross-domain) (specifically dedicated to xDomain stuff).